# cannot crawl pages having load more... link

Tags: import.io

in some web pages like [www.flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/) when we search for something we get results.at the bottom of the page there is link like "view more" or "load more".
when we click it,link is redirected to same page but shows more results.here these pages are not infinite.after some clicks on "view more" or "load more" the page gets terminated.

how to crawl such pages till the end using import.io desktop app?

please help me with this problem

Comment: Hi Krishna,

Flipkart uses a form of infinite scroll called AJAX pagination with JavaScript. Meaning, that data is being hidden by the JavaScript. 

At the moment we do not have an out-of-the box feature at import that deals with this.

We do have some beta features that might help you out at the moment. 

http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/623235-infinite-scroll-and-javascript-prerender-beta

If you would like to chat about a specific issue or website, I would suggest contacting support@import.io for further help.
Thanks